# How to extract conf from ccf and add to ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

for this data:

```
big = runif(60);mangum = runif(61:120)
df = data.frame(big, mangum)
```

We can plot :

```
ccf(df$big, df$mangum) ## we see 2 horizontal dashed lines
```

Now I want to plot via ggplot2, how I can add the 2 horizontal dashed lines (they determine which correlation values are significant) to my ggplot2 plot

```
    df_x <- eval(substitute(big), df)
    df_y <- eval(substitute(mangum), df)
    ccf.object <- ccf(df_x, df_y, plot = FALSE)
    output_table <- cbind(lag = ccf.object$lag, 
                x.corr = ccf.object$acf) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%      mutate(cat = ifelse(x.corr > 0, "green", "red"))
    output_table %>%    ggplot(aes(x = lag, y = x.corr)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = cat))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `stats:::plot.acf`, you will see the default formula for these lines is essentially `c(-1, 1) * qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(n.used)`, where `n.used` is obtained from the output of `ccf`. Therefore, to get a ggplot that matches the output of `ccf`, you can do:

```r
output_table %>%    
  ggplot(aes(x = lag, y = x.corr)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = paste0(cat, 3)), width = 0.4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1, 1) * qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(
    ccf(df$big, df$mangum, plot = FALSE)$n.used), 
    linetype = 2, color = 'blue') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Now we can see this is similar to the results given with the base R plot:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, just if possible i want x axis to be from -20 to 20, each 2 and y axis from 0.20 to 0.80 each 10 is it possible in ggplot2

Comment: @bicton yes, you set the y axis limits and breaks using `scale_y_continuous` and the x axis limits and breaks using `scale_x_continuous`. For example, adding `+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-20, 20), breaks = seq(-20, 20, 2))`